# How to tag a release in Meson when using many subprojects?

Tags: git, meson-build

The project is using [Meson](https://mesonbuild.com/) build system. Main project is using several [subprojects](https://mesonbuild.com/Subprojects.html).

What's the best way to tag a release in Meson when using many subprojects?

What I currently do is:

- tag `v1.0` all the subprojects
- branch the project into `prepare_release_v1.0`
- change the wrap file for each subproject to set `revision=v1.0`
- tag the project itself to `v1.0` (from the branch `prepare_release_v1.0`, not `main`)
- delete the branch `prepare_release_v1.0`

That seems too manual and too error prone. Is there a better solution?

Comment: So, you always move/tag your each subproject/dependency for new release of your main project?

Comment: Not always, but very often.

Comment: Have you considered by default to track main release branch for each subproject?